# Width of Column Of dataset appent to GridView Not Changing Asp.net My Code Attached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

i am firstly creating datatable with value that is,

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Project ID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HighwayCostScore", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BridgeCostScore", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HighwayComplexityScore", typeof(double)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BridgeComplexityScore", typeof(double)));
        DataRow dr;
```

By looping add values in particular column and then add to dataset "dset"

```
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  dset.Tables.Add(dt);
```

then grid view bind with dset,

```
   finalset.Tables.Add(dtt);
   GridViewHcost.DataSource = dset;
```

every thing is fine but Title field has large value so i need to change its column width but i cant i tried many things like,

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;

 protected void GridViewHcost_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[1];
            cell.Width = new Unit("200px");

            for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i != 1)
                {
                    TableCell cell2 = e.Row.Cells[i];
                    cell2.Width = new Unit("50px");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but these are not working for me

i am tired to change just the width of this column "Title"???

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks !
[image]

```
EDITED:

i have attached pic of grid in which i want to increase tile column with and to decrease the rest of column width
```

Comment: you might add a cssclass to the gridview_items and do it by css:
`ItemStyle-CssClass="items"` and `HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"` for the headers for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width for each column in aspx page. e.g

```
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" ></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px"></ItemStyle>


<asp:BoundField HeaderText="abc" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true"
  ControlStyle-CssClass="MyText" DataField="BrandName">
  <ControlStyle CssClass="MyText" Font-Bold="True"></ControlStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```